# How to increase the similarity between specific words in word2vec?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, similarity, sentence

I'm new to use Word2Vec.

I am very curious to know how to increase the similarity between the specific words in word2vec.

Let's say my sentences look like this.(toy example)

sentence1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
sentence2 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']

model = word2vec.Word2Vec([sentence1, sentence2])

What I expect in the result of word2vec is that 'a' and 'b' should be closer than 'a' and 'c'.
This is because there are many pairs of 'a' and 'b' in sentence2 and sentence2 is a training dataset in word2vec model.

How can I make a training dataset to have better similarity between 'a' and 'b' using word2vec?

If you have real applications like this example, please let me know how to use them.

Comment: Why do you prefer `'a'` & `'b'` to be closer than they would be through normal word2vec training? (Have you tried normal training, with a sufficient diverse corpus, and somehow found the results lacking?)

Comment: Because I have to do this in word2vec. I have tried several training datasets  in various way, but I haven't figured out how to increase the similarity between 'a' and 'b'

Comment: I want to know how to make a good corpus to increase the similarity between 'a' and 'b' in this case.

Comment: Is this a specific case (like a homework) or you think this will bring you benefits? Because this that you are proposing goes against the purpose of Word2vec entirelly.

Comment: It is kind of my homework and I think it would be benefit for me.

Comment: As in, you've been assigned as classwork, "make two words have closer word2vec vectors", without any motivating reason for why that's necessary, and without any real-word corpus on which to train them?

Comment: It is because I want to apply word2vec method to another area(not NLP), so I make my custom corpus to apply word2vec.

Comment: Try training GloVe vectors once, although it gives similar results to Word2Vec and it has been proved that SkipGram and CBOW give the same results as modeling the co-occurrence but you can always try. Each corpus is different. For training GloVe like vectors see [mittens](https://github.com/roamanalytics/mittens)